# Magento customers not logged on data

Tags: magento

I need the data of customers who don't create an account on the website. These customers show up in the order list (sales -> orders) but not in the manage customer section. There's no way to filter the order list for this type of customers. Can this be done in the backend or should I write custom query or code to achieve this ? Is it possible for example to add a custom filter in the customers section ? I'm using version 1.4.2

Comment: get this :) the users who check out as guests are not registered customers. You can only get their data from order collection and getting their addressees from there

Comment: Yes you're right. I already lokked at the database and they are not in the customers table. For now a query to get the data will do.
SELECT * FROM `magento142`.`sales_flat_order_address` where customer_id Is null and address_type = 'billing' but this also shows registered customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your queries/collections using orders with `customer_id IS NULL`; these are orders from unregistered users.

Comment: Ben I will try through code now but like I said in other comment: SELECT * FROM magento142.sales_flat_order_address where customer_id Is null and address_type = 'billing' but this also shows registered customers

Comment: Unregistered users can become registered customers so I've added an extra filter to my initial query:
SELECT * FROM magento142.sales_flat_order_address where customer_id Is null and address_type = 'billing' AND email NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM magento142.customer_entity). I will mark ben's respons as answer and like to thank Anton as well